# Struts 2 Action Message - not displayed on the UI

Tags: struts2, action, message

I want to display an info message to the user on submit of the action but the message is not getting displayed. It works if I use `addActionError` but I want to display as an info message and hence using the `addActionMessage`. Please let me know where I went wrong.

```
public void validateUser() {
        List<Product> existingProductList = new ArrayList<Product>();

        try {
            IProductRepository productRepository = daoRepository
                .getProductRepository();
            existingProductList = digestRepository
                .searchDigests(null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
                  }
        for (Product product: existingProductList ) {
            if (prod.getQuartzNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(
                product.getQuartzNumber())) {
            addActionMessage("The Quartz number entered already exists");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my jsp code:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="product_create_header">
        <h2>Create a New product</h2>
    </div>

    <!-- Error messages -->
    <dl id="dyna_product_create_errors" class="error"></dl>


    <form id="product_create_form" method="post">
        <!-- product identifiers -->
        <!-- product details -->
        <fieldset id="product_create_details">
            <legend>product Details</legend>
            <div class="form-element">
                <label for="product_create_name">Name:</label><br />
                <input id="product_create_name" type="text" name="product.name" value="" maxlength="256" /><br />
                <span id="product_create_name_error" class="error"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-element">
                <label for="product_create_presentation_order">Quartz Order:</label><br />
                <input id="product_create_presentation_order" type="text" name="product.quartzOrder" value="" maxlength="256" /><br />
                <span id="product_create_presentation_order_error" class="error"></span>
            </div>

        </fieldset>

        <!-- Form buttons -->
        <div id="product_create_buttons" class="formButtons">
            <button id="product_create_button_cancel" type="button" title="Reset" onclick="resetproductCreateForm();">Reset</button>
            <button id="product_create_button_submit" type="button" title="Submit" onclick="createproduct();">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I see that they have added 
       
 for displaying the error, not sure how to display for messages

Below is my js code:

```
function createproduct() {
    dojo.xhrPost( {
        url :"services/product/create",
        handleAs :"json",
        preventCache :"true",
        load : function(returnObject, ioArgs) {
            if (returnObject.status == "success") {
                product = returnObject.body;
                displayproductDetail();
            }
            else if (returnObject.status == "input") {
                var errorList = dojo.byId("dyna_product_create_errors");
                handleActionErrors(returnObject.actionErrors, errorList);
                handleActionMessage(returnObject.actionMessages, messageList);
                handleCreateproductsFieldErrors(returnObject.fieldErrors);
            }
            else if (returnObject.status == "error") {
                resetproductSearchFormErrors();

                var errorList = dojo.byId("dyna_product_create_errors");
                handleActionErrors(returnObject.actionErrors, errorList);
            }
        },
        error : function(error) {
            handleHTTPError(error);
        },
        form :'product_create_form'
    });
}
```

Comment: Post you JSP where do you try to show action message.

Comment: Updated the post with my code. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String myActionMessage;//Getter and setter Method

public void validateUser() {
    List<Product> existingProductList = new ArrayList<Product>();

    try {
        IProductRepository productRepository = daoRepository
            .getProductRepository();
        existingProductList = digestRepository
            .searchDigests(null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
              }
    for (Product product: existingProductList ) {
        if (prod.getQuartzNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(
            product.getQuartzNumber())) {
        addActionMessage("The Quartz number entered already exists");
        getMyActionMessage("The Quartz number entered already exists");

        break;
    }
   }
}
```

And your result.jsp file

```
<s:actionmessage/>
<s:property value="myActionMessage"/>
```

Comment: Why would you do both?

Comment: one more option to get a action message.most probably action message is collection of string to display some useful information to users.         based upon requirement can use it both.